# Slow queries with PHP application but not with phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

I have a performance problem with my queries to MySQL.

The queries are made using CakePHP 2.x framework but in order to simplify I have created the following test using standard PDO to make the query:

```
public function testPDOconnection()
{
    $query = 'SELECT City.id, lng, lat, country_id, region,
        (`I18n__name`.`content`) AS `City__i18n_name`
        FROM `cities` AS `City`
        INNER JOIN `i18n` AS `I18n__name` ON (`City`.`id` = `I18n__name`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__name`.`model` = "City" AND `I18n__name`.`field` = "name" AND `I18n__name`.`locale` = "eng")
        INNER JOIN `i18n` AS `I18n__desc` ON (`City`.`id` = `I18n__desc`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__desc`.`model` = "City" AND `I18n__desc`.`field` = "desc" AND `I18n__desc`.`locale` = "eng")
        WHERE `City`.`id` IN (641, 47, 216, 62, 323, 164, 306, 1591, 1174, 2690, 1065, 50, 2691, 826, 238, 1037, 2728, 2729, 2730)';
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->server.';dbname='.$this->dbname.';charset=utf8', $this->user, $this->password);

    $start = microtime(true);
    $res = $db->query($query);
    debug(microtime(true) - $start, false); // output around 31.568451 seconds

    debug($res->fetchAll()); // output all results
    $db = null;
}
```

When I run the query over phpMyadmin, it takes around 0.31 seconds to execute (a long time but the final query would be cached in my final application using memcached), but when I run it using my PHP application (using PDO or CakePHP model abstraction layer), it takes around **30 seconds** (unacceptable). Those 2 tests are executed from the same computer (my working laptop) and the database is located in AWS.

I know this query is not the best and could have better optimization, but it is made automatically by the translation behavior of CakePHP.

The database tables are populated with few thousands of entries. This problem does not occur with smaller amount of entries (for example some hundreds), but the 2 queries I was talking about before (phpMyAdmin and my PHP app) are made on the same database.

Any hint about how is this timing difference possible?

Comment: You said yourself that the query is usually cached when you run it from phpMyadmin—does this not explain the difference?

Comment: Is everything on the same server?

Comment: Sounds like you have a crappy link between your web and database servers.

Comment: It is cached on my application using memcached, but is not cached in phpMyAdmin since I can add new IDs to the query and the time does not change @eggyal

Comment: The database is located in AWS, and I connect with a phpMyAdmin located in my local computer, the test on my application is also run from the same computer @Sammitch

Comment: How many results does this query return?  I don't use phpMyadmin, but from recollection it paginates resultsets for display, does it not—presumably by adding `LIMIT` to your queries; if so, then perhaps the delay you are witnessing in your application is the time taken for the full resultset to be transferred to/buffered by the client?

Comment: phpMyAdmin returns 19 results: `Showing rows 0 - 18 (19 total, Query took 0.3046 seconds.)` I have used phpMyAdmin as an example, but using MySQL Java Workbench the result is similar @eggyal
The default limit of 25 entries is not applied